# I have a special case with data representation(e.g., Funnel chart)

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, excel-charts, pivot-chart

Hello Excel masters,

I need your help in representing my data. I have quite complex data, but I don't want to get confused, so I took a simple example:

| Temp(C) | LowerLimit | UpperLimit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -40 | 12 | 1500 |
| 0 | 15.5 | 2000 |
| 25 | 10 | 12000 |
| 80 | 20 | 5000 |

Also I have 2 target lines one with value 10 and another with value 5000

In my case, Funnel chart is perfect, but I want to see the x-axis as well. Also the target lines to display as extra data, as attached in the image.

I appreciate if you could help me with some solution.

It is also very helpful to have other suggestion charts.

Thank you very much in advance

[image]